# Positioning elements vertically in phonegap/html5 app

Tags: android, html, css

I'm trying to position a form field such that it is always 40% down the page and takes up exactly 64% of the screen width, regardless of the screen it is on, the height of the form element is always supposed to be exactly 5% of the screen's height.

This seems like it should be trivial but I have been unable to figure it out based on any of the vertical positioning tutorials here. I can get the positioning correct using code similar to below:

```css
#welcome_email {
    /*positioning */
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 18%;
    width: 64%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 5%;
    /*content*/
    background-color: transparent;
    border: solid;
    border-color: red;
}

#welcome_password {
    /*positioning */
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 18%;
    width: 64%;
    height: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*content*/
    background-color: transparent;
    border: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
                    <input id="welcome_email" placeholder="E-Mail"></input>
                    <br>
                    <input id="welcome_password" placeholder="netid(?)"></input>
```

But then when the soft-keyboard opens on android everything shrinks because the viewport sizes have changed. Is there any way I can achieve both of these goals? Ideally when the keyboard is open it would just focus on the form field like any other form on the internet without rescaling (with scrolling enabled) but when the keyboard is down the element would be positioned in the way depicted above. (You can see similar behavior by opening chrome's CDT for example)

Another way to think of this question is, can I scale and position elements relative to the screen size only once and not everytime the viewport size changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to an extra css propierty to your "welcome" fields:

```
 min-height:5%;
```

If i doesnt work try to use a value in pixels. min-height:30px;

EDIT:

I added a div that cotains the 2 inputs, try it:  http://jsfiddle.net/7aoo6ktf/

```
<div class="container">
<input id="welcome_email" placeholder="E-Mail"></input>
<br>
<input id="welcome_password" placeholder="netid(?)"></input>
</div>

.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 18%;
    width: 64%;
}
#welcome_email {
    /*positioning */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    height: 5%;
    /*content*/
    background-color: transparent;


border: solid;
    border-color: red;
}

#welcome_password {
    /*positioning */
    height: 5%;
    width:100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
/*content*/
background-color: transparent;
border: solid;
border-color: red;
border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but setting a min-height of 5% just causes them to get smushed the same as before, setting a min-height of 30px or 2rem or something causes the text fields to overlap each other.

Comment: Do you need to use `position:absolute` ? This is the reason because they overlap.

Comment: I think so, when I use position:relative they no longer position correctly before the keyboard is visible. position:fixed causes overlapping still.

Comment: That works exactly like I was hoping it would. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

My advice would just be to set a size e.g. `50px;`. What I think might be happening is that once the keyboard appears your application reloads and applies the 5% based on the screen size minus keyboard size.

Comment: The problem for me with setting sizes in pure pixels is that this is a mobile app and so something that is 50px down from the top of the screen on one droid is in a very different spot than 50px down from the top of the screen on another. Since I need these elements to be 5% of the device's height and and 64% of the device's width to match the design specs I was given I don't know how to achieve that while using units like px.